# Can this water damaged fascia be fixed in part without replacing all of the fascia?

Tags: water-damage, gutters, soffit, fascia

I have a small section of fascia with water damage due to gutters not draining correctly. I will fix the gutters but I am worried about the cost and difficulty of repairing the fascia / soffit. It is the only part that has damage to it like this. I would like to avoid having to take out a loan to repair, but I want to repair this before it degrades more.[image]

I am in New Jersey. Is this something I could possibly handle myself and if not, will this be a very costly job?

Comment: Are you sure it's rotting? I looks more like it needs cleaned and a new paint job to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not you can fix this depends on your skillset, which we don't know. Pricing is totally frowned upon on this site. You'll need to get up there and investigate further to determine the extent of the damage. If the soffits are dropping because the fascia has rotted, then the fascia will need to be replaced. How much of it will depend on the amount of rot. If they are dropping due to a few nails pulling out or rusting through, you might luck out by doing some sanding, applying some wood filler and painting. Hold off on fixing the gutters for now because you might have to remove that front piece if you need to replace the fascia.